# Improperly accessing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

The following action is receiving parameters

```
Started POST "/transactions/214/success?locale=it" for 5.171.1.159 at 2018-10-05 13:30:54 +0200
Processing by TransactionsController#success as HTML   
Parameters: {"response-signature-base64"=>"JgO1UzlOubzB0Ic4qSaphxJm4hrFbeR/vF6B/ZanP1s=", "response-signature-algorithm"=>"HmacSHA256", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"214"}
```

However, the cation is not properly processing the parameters.  As a way of proof, the controller action has:

```
  def success
    puts params
    puts "reponse signature base 64"
    puts params[:'response-signature-base64']
```

but the log is not writing any of the above parametric data.  What should I be doing to properly access these parameters?

Comment: Do you have the string "reponse signature base 64" in logs? Did you try `params['response-signature-base64']` (without symbol)

Comment: No that second string is not in the logs.  I have tried passing params without the symbol as well, obtaining the same nil result.  The action does go on to process the subsequent commands.

Comment: Maybe you have some problems with logs? If you add `p "=============="` in any other action does it appears in the logs? Try to use `Rails.logger.info "======"`

Comment: Good pickup.  puts is still rendering nil, but not logger.info.

Answer (score 1):

Compare

> Started POST "/transactions/214/success?locale=it"
>
> Processing by TransactionsController#success as HTML

with code

```
def payment_success
```

You have a route mismatch.

EDIT

`puts` writes to stdout, not to rails log.

Comment: my bad.  question edited  I went and hand typed something from memory.  There is no route mismatch, as the rest of the action processes.

Comment: output of `puts` (stdout) is where your process is started, not in rails logs. Rails logs are usually echoed to stdout, this may be leading you to thing that stdout should be in the log.

Comment: Clarification is useful and appreciated. Yes I was misleading myself (and had somehow assumed that was the case).  Had not looked into (stdout) and its actual function in different environments...